# Getting marker scope in Angular Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

I have a map built with Angular UI's library for Google Maps (http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)

I need to access the scope of a marker *outside* of a marker event handler.  Normally, I can access the scope as follows, inside an event handler:

```
vm.markerEvents = {
    click: function (marker, eventName, scope) {
        console.log(scope);  // can access the marker scope
    }
};

<ui-gmap-google-map ...>
    <ui-gmap-markers events="vm.markerEvents" ....></ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I would like to be able to modify properties on the scope of a marker (notably `labelClass`) *outside* of the event handler shown above.

I can get the Marker objects using the Markers controller, but the scope is not available with this method:

```
var markers = vm.markersControl.getGMarkers();
console.log(markers);

markers[0].property = 'newValue'; // does not propagate to map
markers[0].scope.property = 'newValue' // what I'm looking for (does not exist)
```

Changing properties on the marker object itself does not propagate to the map, which is why I need to change them on the scope.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Can get the google map marker objects and do things like `marker.setVisible(true)` using gmap api. Use the `control` objects in ui-map options to be able to expose gmap api in your controller

Comment: I'm trying to modify the class of the marker with `labelClass`.  It looks like you can't modify the markers with jQuery (so no `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()`), so I was using the `labelClass` property on the scope.

With the `mouseout` and `mouseover` events, I can change `labelClass` to `map-marker` normally and `map-marker hovered` when hovered over -- this works fine.  However, I need to do this from outside of the events as well, from a click handler from a button in a different directive.

Comment: I am thinking now I may be able to use that `.setVisible()` method to trigger an event just to catch the scope and save it... seems hacky, but if there are any other options I'm open to hearing them.

Comment: Need to realize that maps api marker objects are not the same object references you have in your scope. They go through `new google.maps.Marker()`. But if you use the `control` options in ui-maps docs you can access all the various google map api's for the map itself, markers , layers etc